# Simplify3D setup for Athorbot Brother 3D Printer

Tags: software, simplify3d

Using Simplyfy3D printing software I am not sure which printer mine is called in the list (or which substitute to use).
I have an [Athorbot Brother 3D Printer](https://athorbot.com/collections/3d-printers/products/athorbot-brother-easy-assemble-diy-desktop-3d-printer-large-printing-size-300-300-300mm).

On the screen of the controller, it says "Mendel Ready".

So any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Steve and welcome to SE.3DPrinting! Did you change the firmware of the printer? Usually that message is displayed after you "booted up" the firmware. "Mendel ready" would suggest that the incorrect firmware is loaded onto your printer as you do not have a "Mendel". Please add some more info to the question whether or not you changed the firmware. When that is clear, people can write better tailored answers for you. If this is the stock firmware, the message is configured by the manufacturer of the printer probably they did not pay attention in setting the correct `CUSTOM_MACHINE_NAME`.

Comment: [This is a Mendel](https://reprap.org/mediawiki/images/thumb/1/1f/Mendel.jpg/800px-Mendel.jpg)